# How to make hero region background transparent in oracle apex?

Tags: css, oracle-apex, transparent

I tried writing these to the inline:

```
  .t-HeroRegion {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: transparent;
        background-size: cover;
}

.t-HeroRegion-title {
        background-color: "ffffff"
}

.t-Body{
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.t-HeroRegion-wrap {
        background-color: transparent;
}
```

but nothing works. Please help.

I also tried putting this line to the appearance:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following line on Region Attributes --> **Advanced --> Custom Attributes**

```
style="background-color: transparent;"
```

Comment: It is not working :((

Comment: Please make sure you add it on Advanced, not on Appearance as it appears in your image above.

Comment: yes still not working

Answer (score 0):

i've tried to add the modifier to the right spot but the background of the hero region icon is still colored

I get more luck adding this to the css inline param of the page:

```
.t-HeroRegion-icon {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
}
```